# Getting express server to accept CORS request

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have my express server running on http://localhost:3000  (I call this web-server)
I have another application running on localhost:8100  (I call this simply 'app')

When my app makes a call to the webserver I receive the message:

> "XMLHTTPReqeust cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:81000' is therefore not allowed acecss"

This message shows up in the browser console.

I have setup the following options in the middleware of my node webserver

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT, POST,DELETE');
```

After reading few stackoverfow questions, I also added the following:

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');
```

however this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: You also need to allow `OPTIONS` method in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Answer (score 32):

I use cors and implement it so, it's very simple

`var cors=require('cors');`

`app.use(cors({origin:true,credentials: true}));`

Comment: This for me worked. Plain and simple. You just got to "npm install cors" for it to work.

Comment: This is the best Solution for Accept all origins because origin:"*" don't work

Answer (score 24):

I personally prefer the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module. The code is really simple:

```
var whitelist = [
    'http://0.0.0.0:3000',
];
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback){
        var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
    },
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: I would recommend to use cors module as Thomas suggested, rather then deal with headers stuff. It is easy to setup and use. It tu 30 seconds to solve general issues.

Answer (score 24):

You also need to allow `OPTIONS` method in the header.

I have this middleware for cors:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR_URL"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Accept,X-Custom-Header");

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    return next();
};
```

**PS.** The error you get is due to the fact of how cross-origin request works. To make a long story short, the browser might first send a `pre-flight` request with method `OPTIONS` to get allowed origins, headers and methods. So for this request you should return nothing but the `Access-Control-*` headers. If the `pre-flight` went fine, the browser will continue with the original request.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thank you! `if (req.method === "OPTIONS")` was what was missing for me

Comment: Handling the `OPTIONS` method by sending the `200` status code helped. Also, look at this diagram for more understanding. The part where we need to handle `OPTIONS` is at the end of the diagram.
https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

Comment: Additional Resources to this thread 
1. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight


Adding to @Felippe Regazio answers.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently cors module didn't work.

Using the hints given above I used the following code:

```
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  } else {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  }
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and stumbled for about an hour. The solution was actually simple--just enable CORS for [preflight operations](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

```
app.options('*', cors()); // include before other routes
```

Comment: combined with runtimeZero if-else code, this worked perfectly for me!
More details [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

Comment: The fact that the handling of CORS needs to be included before other routes helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You must take in consideration your preflight request also. I suggest you to add the "cors" npm package on your project, and start it with this following configurations:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH' , 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    origin: true
}));
```

This will enable Cross Origin Requests for any address with the listed methods. The origin parameter is very flexible, you can delimiter a set of address, all address or by regex, for example. Here is the package docs:

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd had cracked this one before but once I swapped back from IIS to IIS Express, I started to get the error again!!

Started to Google once again and tried numerous suggestions, including the ones above but none of them worked until I found this article from [Melvin's Web Stuff - Enable CORS IIS Express](http://www.melvinswebstuff.com/blog/2015/01/02/enable-cors-iisexpress/) which suggested the following:

Add the following 2 lines to the `<customHeaders>` section under the `<httpProtocol>` section:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

to the applicationhost.config located in:

```
%HOMEPATH%\Documents\IISExpress\config
```

The final result should look like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <clear />
         <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />   
   </customHeaders>
   <redirectHeaders>
      <clear />
   </redirectHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This worked nicely for me but note that I didn't need the above when running in IIS.