# Form Submit shows strange error in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I'm working on a small ToDo app where I've Angular as front-end and Node.js/Express/Mongo as middleware/backend.

While I submit Login in my Login form, it hits the login API, however it returns one strange output in the console saying

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login/ 0 {}

(see screenshot below) which doesn't allow me to get the dashboard even after successful login.

I've enabled CORS through installing the `cors` NPM module. and I've checked RESTFul services in Postman, and all are working fine.

[Updated] This is how I've enabled the CORS in my `express.js`'s `app.js` file.

```
let cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

[image: Error in console]

Comment: Please share your CORS settings/code. This is a common error when the port is not configured for CORS in your api.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Updated mate.

Comment: Is you API [set to accept `OPTIONS` request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483675/getting-express-server-to-accept-cors-request) ?

Comment: @Nicolas I hope, I'm doing it through the CORS module (which I've updated in my post). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a [known nodejs issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1325) that is still open.

Based on the open github, seems that the best recommendation is to try something like this:

> you need to allow both:

```
// Http.OPTIONS method for request that is hitting " apiUrl =https://127.0.0.1:3000/login".
// Allow CORS like below:
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
```

Another great idea is to use the angular proxy settings for local development so that you will not need to add CORS for localhost at all.

Very good guidance [in this SO answer here on setting up a proxy for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server) If this work, then you can make 100% sure that it is indeed a CORS problem.

Answer (score 2):

before a CORS request is sent to the server, clients will always send this "OPTIONS" request as a "preflight request", soliciting supported methods from the server.

This request being blocked may be an indicator of a wrong CORS configuration or an explicit block of all "OPTIONS" requests from the server. (CORS needs to be configured on the server as well).

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I hope, I've done it using the CORS npm module. Do I need to try something else?

Comment: You could try to allow all `OPTIONS` request on your backend.

Comment: Do you mean by setting the appropriate header like this `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");`  ??

Comment: Yes, this is what I would try.

Comment: Sure, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

To handle CORS in express you dont need to add any dependency.
Notice that http://localhost:4200 is you angular app.

This worked for me:

```
//Add here whatever route you are using for the api.
app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  //Where http://localhost:4200 is the angular app
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'),
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  next();
})
```

Note:
This goes after the place where you import the routes and before where you use them. kind of like:

```
const apiRouter = require('./app_api/routes/api_routes');
//The code i posted here
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```