# Access blocked by CORS in express server

Tags: typescript, express, cors, passport.js, nuxtjs

I am getting the following error when sending a POST api request to my express server.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8081/application' from origin 'localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The express server is using the npm cors package and passport jwt authentication strategy.

```
privateServer.use(cors());
registerJWTAuthentication();
  privateServer.all('*', authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false,
  }));
privateServer.addRouter('/application', privateApplicationRouter);
```

I am sending this request with axios from a nuxtjs application.

```
const result = await axios.post('localhost:8081/application', payload);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this CORS problem?

Comment: I’ve suggested an edit to the question title - the answer to “how to handle CORS problems” would be along the lines of “weep into a deep dark well”, or “burn it all and walk away” 

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483675/getting-express-server-to-accept-cors-request

Comment: do not work.
I have a public server too (withour authentication) there it works withour any changes.

Comment: Try adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to your axios request on the frontend. Ususally cors enables all origins when running on your local machine. I had issues even with cors once i deployed it to a serverless environment and other server stuff. Maybe that helps :/

Answer (score -1):

the cors middleware allows you to pass options, you can do something like :

```
  {
      "origin": "localhost:8083",
      "credentials": true,
  }
```

Note that 'origin' can accept an array of origins you are allowing, and your request should also contain :

```
 {
     credentials: 'include',
 }
```

In order for the cookies to be sent,

Hope it helps ...