# Preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status problem and i don't know why, i imported everything right

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting this error where it says "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." Anyone have any idea on what could it be?

This is my code on backend:

app.js

```
app.delete("api/posts/:id", (req,res,next) =>{
  console.log(req.params.id);
  res.status(200).json({message: 'post deleted!'})
})
```

This is the code on frontend:

posts.service.ts:

```
deletePost(postId: string) {
    this.http
      .delete('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('deleted');
      });
  }
```

post-list.component.ts

```
onDelete(postId: string) {
    this.postsService.deletePost(postId);
  }
```

And post-list.component.html:

```
<button mat-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(post.id)">DELETE</button>
```

Note that I DID ALLOW CORS in my code, here's the proof:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

Here's a picture of the problem:
[image: Problem]

Comment: Check in your browser if the headers are actually there in the OPTIONS response..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preflight requests are not handeled as "normal" request. They have the http OPTIONS header.So after your code snippet where you set the CORS header just add the following lines:

```
app.options('/*', (_, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This just sets the status to 200 and should fix your problem.

Comment: Still, I have a problem with 404 not found on delete.. any ideas how to solve that one? Btw this one is solved, thanks!

Comment: Where is this error metioned? I don´t find it

Comment: It was under that one, here: https://prnt.sc/14dugss

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490521/4102907 @MilošMilutinov Milutinov

Comment: This saved me :-) made preflight request valid