# Node JS passport-saml authentication fails with "preflight request doesn't pass access control check" when deploying multiple instance using pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2, adfs, passport-saml

I have tried plenty of answers posted for a similar question but my issue is slightly different from straight forward `CORS` issue.

I am using `passport-saml` with my Node JS app to authenticate my web-application with ADFS. Everything works fine as long as I deploy only one instance of the app but as soon as I run multiple instances using `pm2` I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.....' 
(redirected from 'https://sampleserver.com/get/employee') 
from origin 'https://sampleserver.com' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my pm2 config file:

```
{
    "apps": [
    {
        "name" : "sample-worker",
        "script" : "./app",
        "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "autorestart" : true,
        "instances" : 3,
        "exec_mode" : "cluster",
        "instance_var": "INSTANCE_ID"
    }
    ]
}
```

Based on some of the questions posted online I tried the following:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

ALSO

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

And also tried some other options from the questions below:

[Question_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

[Question_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105091/cors-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-how-to-s)

[Question_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860273/preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-it-does-not-have-http-ok-st)

Please let me know if you would need any other information to shed some more light on the issue. I really appreciate any help I can get on this. I've been stuck on this for days now.

P.S. The app works perfectly fine when only a single instance is deployed - regardless of whether it is deployed using `node` command or `pm2` command.

Edit:
This is the code that checks for presence of a user in the request object:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user));
            next();
        } else {
            console.log("***************************");
            console.log('User not authenticated, routing to AD for authentication');
            console.log('***************************');
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798164/cors-issue-with-ambassador-accessing-azuread

Comment: Not really because the issue is not with handling expired tokens but with parallel instances not being able to handle the authentication. I wonder why though because the request object will remain the same and it is already authenticated :(

Comment: In both cases, the problem is that the API request does not have a valid session: in your case because a different instance is chosen, in the other case because the session is expired. Or how do you share sessions between the two instances?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have added the logic that is used to check for a user in the post. Wouldn't the request object be same for each of the app/instance? If not, then what would be a solution in my situation? I wonder how do other load balanced apps work?

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Setting up a DB session store solved the issue. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a CORS problem, but a session management problem:

After successful SAML logon flow, the server issues a session cookie, which the browser re-sends with every subsequent request.

For this to work with multiple backend instances, it must be ensured that a session cookie that was issued by *one* instance is also recognized by all *other* instances. In other words: The instances need a *common* session store, for example a database. Storing sessions in a global Node.js variable does not work, because every instance has its own global variables.

The [`pm2` documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#statelessify-your-application) also says as much.