# How should i configure CORS to avoid https request errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I get the following message:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api-domain' from origin 'website-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"

This is how i handle the requests in my app.js file.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader(
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
next();
});
```

I tried using my domain instead of the '*', but it doesnt work either.

Am i missing something here?

edit:
i also tried this solution to handle preflight requests but it didnt work

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
// CORS headers
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR_URL"); // 
restrict it to the required domain
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
"GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
// Set custom headers for CORS
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content- 
type,Accept,X-Custom-Header");

if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.status(200).end();
}

return next();
};
```

Comment: Try `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: None`.

Comment: Preflight request uses OPTIONS http method. Make sure your server handles such requests, and it does it correctly.

Comment: @JakubMatczak i clearly showed how i handle the requests, and its not working.

Comment: You are handling regular requests with cors headers which is good.  Additionally, you'll need to handle preflight requests.  That is what is failing.

Comment: @Nicolas you actually clearly showed that the preflight request fails with non-200 response. Your code just shows what headers are being added, but that's not everything.

Comment: @James should i handle that after the regular requests?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483675/getting-express-server-to-accept-cors-request

Comment: Your current cors solution doesn't correctly end with an OK status code when the method is OPTIONS. Both the error, and your provided code, prove this. Using a standardized package, such as `cors` as suggested below, and configuring it properly to work with your environment and needs, is the better route. I assume your current setup ultimately results in the options request being responded to with a 404 because you have no routes matching OPTIONS method for your given route. The cors middleware, when configured properly, does this for you.

Answer (score -2):

First remove all of your existing header. Do it with cors package.

Step 1: install the cors `npm install cors`

Step 2: import it `var cors = require('cors')`

Step 3: simply use in app. `app.use(cors())`

You can configure cors package. See details from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work.